# Please guide me where i am wrong

Tags: homework-and-exercises, surface-tension, bubbles

This is the question:

> The pressure inside two soap bubbles is 1.01 and 1.02 atm. What is the ratio of their volumes?

This is what i did:

Formula:

\begin{align}
P & = \frac{4 S}{r}
\end{align}
From there:
\begin{align}
\frac{P_1}{P_2} & = \frac{r_2}{r_1} \\
\frac{\frac{4}{3} \pi r_1^3}{\frac{4}{3} \pi r_2^3} & = \left ( \frac{P_2}{P_1} \right )^3 = \left ( \frac{1.02}{1.01} \right )^3 = 1.0299
\end{align}

The correct answer given in the booklet is 8.

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what you are asking. Also you might want the title of the question to reflect its content.

Comment: Where i am doing mistake so that i am not getting correct answer?

Comment: What are your variables? Is $ \gamma $ the radius of the bubbles?

Comment: Its not $ \gamma$ it is $p$ for excess pressure inside soap bubble and $r$ is there for radius  sorry my writing is very poor

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for “check my work” problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic). You might get a better response at a more appropriate site.  [Here’s one to consider.](http://www.physicsforums.com), but there are others.

Comment: But i am not asking for solution. I am just asking where i am wrong

Comment: I do know its not a homework site

Comment: Please read our [FAQ on question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ p $ is excess pressure then you should have used $ p_{1}=(1.01-1) = 0.01 $ atm  and  $ p_{2}=(1.02-1) = 0.02 $ atm. After making this correction your ratio of $ \left ( \frac{0.02}{0.01} \right )^3 = 8 $ works out.